# check that one radio button for each fieldset has been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form containing 10 fieldsets.

I want to be able to check that when the form is submitted, each fieldset has a radio button selected.

I've scoured similar posts and tried most/all of the answers without success so wondered if anyone can offer some advice on where I'm going wrong?

An example of the html:

```
    <div class="questions">
      <fieldset>
        <h2>If you could have any superpower, what would it be? </h2>
        <div class="row question9">
            <label for="Q9A1" class="Q9 A1">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q9A1" value="Q9A1" name="Q9">
              Flight </label>
            <label for="Q9A2" class="Q9 A2">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q9A2" value="Q9A2" name="Q9">
              Super speed </label>
            <label for="Q9A3" class="Q9 A3">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q9A3" value="Q9A3" name="Q9">
              X­ray vision </label>
            <label for="Q9A4" class="Q9 A4">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q9A4" value="Q9A4" name="Q9">
              Super strength </label>
            <label for="Q9A5" class="Q9 A5">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q9A5" value="Q9A5" name="Q9">
              See into the future </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<div>
<div class="questions">
    <fieldset>
        <h2>If you could have any superpower, what would it be?</h2>
        <div class="row question10">
            <label for="Q10A1" class="Q10 A1">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q10A1" value="Q10A1" name="Q10">
              Flight </label>
            <label for="Q10A2" class="Q10 A2">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q10A2" value="Q10A2" name="Q10">
              Super speed </label>
            <label for="Q10A3" class="Q10 A3">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q10A3" value="Q10A3" name="Q10">
              X­ray vision </label>
            <label for="Q10A4" class="Q10 A4">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q10A4" value="Q10A4" name="Q10">
              Super strength </label>
            <label for="Q10A5" class="Q10 A5">
              <input type="radio" class="styled" id="Q10A5" value="Q10A5" name="Q10">
              See into the future </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

This is where I've got up to with the jQuery:

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(){
        var flag;
        $('.questions')
            .each(function(){
                flag = false;
                if(!$('.question10 input[type="checkbox"]' .is(':checked'))
                return false;
                flag = true;
        });
        if (flag)
            alert("submitted");
        else
            alert("Not submitted");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply do that:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var flag = true;

    $('.questions').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
            flag = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (flag)
        alert("submitted");
    else
        alert("Not submitted");
});
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

**EDIT:**

If you are using radio buttons, as you can check only one per question, another way you could do it is:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var totalQuestions = $('.questions').length;
    var totalAnswers = $('.questions').find(':radio:checked').length;

    if (totalQuestions == totalAnswers)
        alert("submitted");
    else
        alert("Not submitted");
});
```

Comment: That's perfect. I have just noticed an error in my original script in that I was referencing checkbox when they're actually radio. Using your answer and changing checkbox to radio has solved this one for me!

Comment: I've edited my answer with another solution, you can choose which suits you better. Glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below approach for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    var flag;
    $('.questions').each(function(){
        flag = false;
      var groupName = $(this).find("input[type='radio']:first").attr('name');
      var answer = $("input[name="+ groupName +"]:checked").val();
      if(typeof answer != "undefined" && answer != "undefined"){
        flag = true;
      }
      else
      {
        flag = false;
        return false;
      }
    });  
    if(flag == false){
        alert("Please select all the answers");
    }
    else{
     alert("all the answers are selected");
    }
    });
});
```